# Sure-fire plugin error (even though i have it in my pom.xml) when i do "maven install" on my java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I am new to using Maven, so i might be missing something. I keep getting the below error, every time i run "maven install" or "maven test". I have already tried adding the sure-fire plugin to my pom.xml file. Which i have added below. What else could be causing the problem?
Here is the error that keeps popping up in my console every time i run the command

[image]

Here is the pom.xml for my project, where i have added the sure-fire plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.Project</groupId>
    <artifactId>myprofile</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myprofile</name>
    <description>Service to retrieve my profile</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vertx.version>3.6.0</vertx.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.1.0</junit-jupiter.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.8.0</assertj-core.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
                <artifactId>vertx-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${vertx.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.19.1</version>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                  <version>5.0.3</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
                                        <Main-Verticle>com.company.Project.myProfileVerticle</Main-Verticle>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <artifactSet/>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Deploy to Nexus -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>Projectreleases</id>
            <url>http://artifactory.company.local/artifactory/ProjectReleases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>Projectsnapshots</id>
            <url>http://artifactory.company.local/artifactory/ProjectSnapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because dependency junit-jupiter-engine inside build plugin is different from dependency declared on dependencies (5.0.3 versus 5.1.0).